# Marvel Heroes Creator NimbusLookAndFeel exception

Tags: java

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'm trying to run the marvel character creator 2.1.2 JAR file, but I keep getting this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel
```

Here is what I have:

```
java version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6647622

Comment: That bug isn’t an explanation for the behavior, the class that cannot be found is the new name of the class. The class was changed back in 2008 which is nearly 15 years ago.  The author is using a recent version of Java, not Java 6, which hasn’t been supported or updated in over a decade.